# Proof $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx < \infty \Leftrightarrow \sum_{n=0}^\infty f(n) < \infty$

Tags: integration, analysis, proof-writing

Let $f: [0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ be monotonus decreasing.

How can one prove that

$$\int_0^\infty f(x)dx < \infty \Leftrightarrow \sum_{n=0}^\infty f(n) < \infty$$

I don't know because it compares an infinite series with an improper integral.

Comment: Draw a picture.

Comment: Integral comparison test. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence

Comment: $f(n) \geq \int_n^{n+1} f(x) dx  \geq f(n+1)$.

Comment: This is the integral test to verify if one series is convergent.

Comment: Try to draw a graph to interpret the meaning of the integral and see if you can spot the relationship between the two expressions,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a partition $ \Pi = \{x_0=0, 1, 2, \cdots, n\}  $ and choose $\mathbb{N_0}$ as points to evaluate then the Riemann sum looks like $ \sum_0^n f(n)\Delta x = \sum_0^n f(n)$ which is exactly the partial sum of the series, and as you chose the least element in each interval and $f$ is decreasing this is a superior sum and therefore greater or equal to the infimum of them.

If you choose $\mathbb{N}$ without $0$ to evaluate, you get an inferior sum which equals to the series minus the first term and is less than or equal to the supremum of the inferior sums.

If the integral converges, the supremum of inferior sums equals the infimum of the superior sums then, by comparison, your series is less than or equal to an already convergent series, thus converges.

If the series converges then your superior sums for the integral are bounded from above, then, the integral is bounded, so, as it is increasing (for $f$ is non negative) it converges.